# How to call a jquery function from an ActionResult in the Controller using Mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
  public  ActionResult Deletecart(int id)
    {

        cartList = (List<Product>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["cartList"];
        Product p = cartList.SingleOrDefault(item => item.ProductId == id);
        cartList.Remove(p);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["cartList"] = cartList;
        int cartLen = cartList.Count;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["CartLen"] = cartLen;
        //*** xxx  *//

       return ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "viewKart();", true);            

    }
```

I want to view the cart whenever I delete the items from it. This cart can be viewed by calling the jquery function followed by the delete ActionResult in the controller. I am gettinmg the error in this.Page argument of the script register method in controller.
The jquery function to be called is as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//alert("hello");
function viewKart() {
    // alert("hello");
    $("#table").empty();
    debugger;
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("ViewCart", "home")',
     function (data) {
         debugger;

         if (data == "" || data == null) {

             $(window).scrollTop(0);
             $("#table").append("<h2> No results found ! </h2>");

         }
         if (data != null) {
             $.each(data, function (index, item) {


                 var len = data.length;
                 alert(len);
                 var txt = "";
                 if (len > 0) {


                     for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                         if (data[i].ProductId && data[i].Name && data[i].ShortDescription && data[i].MediumImage && data[i].Price && data[i].IconImage) {
                             //alert(data)
                             //var date = new Date(parseInt(data[i].date.substr(6)));
                             var Photoq = "/Images/HomeImages/" + data[i].MediumImage;

                             //alert(Photoq);
                             //<img id="imgAd" src="/Images/HomeImages/1.jpg" width="181px" height="215px" alt="img">
                             var Photo = "<img id='imgAd' src='" + Photoq + "' width='100px' height='100px' alt='img'/>";

                             //alert(Photo);

                             txt += '<tr><td><div id ="result1" ><div>' + Photo + '</div> <div ><div>' + '<div id="hello">' + data[i].ProductId + '</div>' + "</br> Name- " + data[i].Name + "</br> Description " + data[i].ShortDescription + ", </br>" +'<div class="totals">'+ data[i].Price+'</div>' + '<button class="Btnremove" type="button" data-id="' + data[i].ProductId + '">Remove</button>' + "</br>";
                             //txt += data[i].ProductId + Photo  + " &nbsp " + data[i].Name + " &nbsp " + data[i].ShortDescription +"&nbsp" + data[i].Price+"</br>" ;

                         }

                         $(document).on('click', ".Btnremove", function (event) {
                             debugger;
                             var id = $(this).data('id');
                             $(this).closest('tr').removeData();
                             alert('ashj')
                             debugger;
                             $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Deletecart", "home")', {
                                 id: $(this).data('id')
                             }, location.reload(true), function (data) {
                                 if (data == null) {
                                     alert('Cart is empty');
                                 }

                             });



                             @*$.getJSON('@Url.Action("Deletecart", "home")', {
                                id: $(this).data('id')
                             },location.reload(true), function (data) {

                            });*@
                         });                             



                     }
                     if (txt != "") {
                         $("#table").append(txt);

                     }

                 }
                 return false;
             });

         }

     })
     $("#popupdiv").dialog({
         title: "AddCart",
         width: 630,
         height: 450,
         modal: true,
         buttons: {
             Close: function () {
                 $(this).dialog('close')
             }
         }
     })



        //$("#popupdiv").dialog("open")
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: What you are returning is not an instance of ActionResult... this would probably have worked in webforms ...

Comment: Yes, I saw this one line code in web forms example but its not working in the MVC

Comment: They are very different frameworks .. include more of the code in your view and maybe it'll be easier for someone to provide a solution

Comment: _but its not working in the MVC_ Thats because its MVC not WebForms!

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Hi stephen, What should I do now ? Intellisense is showing these methods. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you trying to do, but if the script is on the page then whats the point of `RegisterStartupScript`? If you calling `Deletecart` using ajax, then maybe `return Json(true); to indicate success, then check the return value, and if true, call your `viewKart` function (`viewKart` and `Deletecart` should be separate functions)

Comment: Looking at your code I assume you have a table showing items that have been added to the cart. In your `Deletecart` method, if you just return a value indicating success, then all that would be necessary is  to delete the row the button is on. I does not seem necessary to rebuild the whole table again which is what the `viewKart` function appears to be doing.

Comment: The row would be deleted but we have to update the application cache as well in which the list is there of the items.

Comment: Not sure I understand. If the `Deletecart` method is getting the current cart from Session, removing the deleted item, then saving the modified cart back to session, and finally return something to indicate success, then what is the problem?

Comment: I want that dialog box should not disappear when I remove the item. It should call the Action in controller and then return the modified list and again call the viewKart() of jquery to again display the dialog box.

Comment: Then don't close the dialog. Sorry, but nothing in your code makes sense to me. Perhaps you should look at tried and tested solutions like [nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/)

Comment: Hey @StephenMuecke , I got the solution for this. Now dialog box is not even closing and refreshes the new list lying in he application cache. Thanks for devoting time :) .

Answer (score 1):

You can return [JavaScriptResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.javascriptresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) using [JavaScript()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.javascript%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) this way:

```
public  ActionResult Deletecart(int id)
{
   string script = "viewKart();";
   return JavaScript(script);
}
```

You can also refer [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1735868.aspx?Call%20Javascript%20Function%20in%20MVC%20Controller%20)